# How to retrieve multiple rows from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

For example, I have a `users` table, and `posts`.
With `users` storing the user info, and `posts`, storing posts associated with that user.

`{user: {user_id: 1, username: "test"}, posts: [{post_id: 1, message: "post 1"}, {post_id: 2, post: "message 2"}]}`

How can I achieve this without doing two separate queries? i.e. first select user from users table, then select posts by the user and parsing it myself.

I have tried:

`SELECT user.id, user.username,  (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user = user.id) from users`

in hopes of getting both the user info and the posts associated, but I am getting the error: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: "Best" & "efficient" don't mean anything in particular. Please show what you are able to do. [homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre] PS Please indent code & data reasonably. See the edit help & any Q&A with code whatsoever re formatting. Please don't put anything needed to ask only in your post title. "For example"--an example of what? PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. Ask 1 question.

Comment: @philipxy ive amended my question to specifically ask for how to retrieve multiple rows so it is more specific, and i removed the alternative method which i provide previously. is this better?

Comment: Please read & act on all my comment & its links. PS How is asking for (possibly) multiple rows different from any query whatsoever? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please either ask about bad code with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal with relevant parts you can do. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. PS Again: "Please indent code & data reasonably. See the edit help"

Answer (score 1):

stan,

if I understand your question right,

step 1 -  you can assign a post to a user by having a user_id column in the posts table, that way you can just use this query to select all user posts

```
SELECT post_id , post FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id` = 1;
```

step 2 - use join

```sql
SELECT user.user_id, user.username, posts.post_id, posts.post
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `posts` ON post.user_id = 1;
```